# How to find the stack size of printf (library function)?

Tags: linux, gcc, static-libraries, stack-trace

I want to collect the stack size of all library functions. Please let me know if there is any tool to do this or method.?

Comment: All vararg/stdarg functions have an indefinite stack usage.

Comment: The stack size of printf is generally determined by how it is called.  Calling `printf ("%c", 33)` is way different than calling it with `printf ("%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d\n%d %d %d %d", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14)`

Comment: @wallyk thanks. I want to analyse size of both stacks ?    printf ("%c", 33) is way different than calling it with printf ("%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d\n%d %d %d %d", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14)

Answer (score 0):

with regular c printf
I just tried to print a long string and got this error:

"Error  2   error C2026: string too big, trailing characters truncated"

some more info:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dddywwsc.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396